# Why do I get a syntax error for assembly language?

Tags: debugging, ubuntu, assembly, syntax

I copied an assembly code in an attempt to get it compiled. However,it is saying that I am facing syntax error at line 25.

Why is this so?

GNU nano 2.2.6                                                        File: shell.asm

```
Section .text

global _start
_start:

jmp short GotoCall

shellcode:

        pop esi
        xor eax, eax
        mov byte [esi + 7], al  
        lea ebx, [esi]
        mov long [esi + 8], ebx
        mov long [esi + 12], eax
        mov byte al, 0x0b
        mov ebx, esi
        lea ecx, [esi + 8]
        lea edx, [esi + 12]
        int 0x80

GotoCall:

        Call    shellcode
        db      ‘/bin/shJAAAAKKKK’
```

Answer (score 4):

You copy/pasted that from the web (just guessing) and it's using the wrong kind of quotes:

```
Character: ‘ U+2018
Name: LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
```

Use single-quotes from the ASCII subset:

```
    db      '/bin/shJAAAAKKKK'
```